# Is there a way to save the output of a whole jupyter notebook to a txt file or similar without using command line but from inside the notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, output, jupyter, ibm-watson

I'm having a quite disturbing issue. I'm running a notebook job on **Watson Studio** and my job is failing after some execution time. 
 The time varies, sometimes it takes 40 min to fail and sometimes it takes 2 hours. The *Watson log* doesn't provide any helpul information, except for this line, that I see is repeated several times:

```
[I 2019-09-10 00:39:23.357 NotebookApp] [_get_model_from_row] Output could not be parsed
```

I don't know what that means, since I don't have any functions or classes created called `_get_model_from_row`.

There is no Python traceback on the log, it only spits out the jupyter console's output.

**Now my question is**, since I'm working on a limited and closed environment such as Watson Studio (no command line available):

*Is there a way to save the whole notebook's output to a file?* Is there some code that could be executed from inside the notebook cells to save its output to a file? If so, how could I do this?

If someone also has any information about the **error** I'm facing in the log or it rings a bell, it will also be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below prints out **script name**, **line no.** and **error** on the console

```
try:
    # Add your code here
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print("Exception occurred while processing: {param1}, line {param2}, {param3}".format(param1=fname, param2=exc_tb.tb_lineno, param3=exc_type))
```

Please include pickle in your code to save object to file inclusive of outputs.

Refer to example - https://www.thoughtco.com/using-pickle-to-save-objects-2813661

Comment: Hi @ AnswerSeeker, thank you very much for your answer. This cell is to be included at the end of the notebook or at the beginning?

Comment: Place your code in-between the try and except clause. If exception occurs, it will print out the error on console.